# Struts 2 Error Handling - How do I get the stackTrace and exception attribute?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I'm working with Struts2 and I'm having an issue with it's error handling mechanism.
What I would like to do is to get the **stackTrace** and **exception**
attributes in order to use it inside an action class (as for printing on
the console) or inside a JSP page (without using taglibs).

Bellow there is a snippet of my struts.xml file:

```
<default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>

    <global-results>
        <result name="Exception" type="redirect">/error.action</result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping result="Exception"   exception="java.lang.Exception" />
    </global-exception-mappings>

    <action name="error" class="fend.ErrorAction">
        <result>/error.jsp</result>
        <interceptor-ref name="configStack"/>
    </action>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

in your JSP:

```
Exception : <s:property value="%{exception}" />

Exception stacktrace: <s:property value="exceptionStack"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same set up as you except I redirect my exception to a JSP page exception.jsp.

In that page I have the following:

```
 <s:set name="ex" value="%{exception}" scope="page"/>
```

I know you want to avoid tag libs but perhaps the exception property will be available in your action?  I remember having trouble passing the exception to my action as an Exception Object.  I couuld only pass it as a string (my memory is fuzzy on this, its been a while)

In the end I redirected to a JSP page, included the above s:set tag and the following JSP sciptlet:

```
<%
Exception exMsg = (Exception)pageContext.getAttribute("ex");
logger.logException(application.getRealPath("")+ "/WEB-INF/error.txt",exMsg);
%>

<br/><br/>User friendly message here
```

The logger class got the stack trace from the Exception class and logs it to a file:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = exception.getStackTrace();
```

I remember having to get this done so it was one of those situations where I had to settle for some messy code but it worked...  If you figure our something better let me know

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor* to log your exceptions at a desired log level (and a desired logger too). ([Read the documentation here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ExceptionMappingInterceptor.html))

The easiest way would be to customize the *defaultStack* in your struts.xml as below:

```
<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
  <interceptor-ref name="exception">
     <param name="logEnabled">true</param>
     <param name="logCategory">com.mycompany.app.unhandled</param>
     <param name="logLevel">WARN</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
  ........
</interceptor-stack>
```